# copy constructor of linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Here is the definition and implementation of my linked list class template. the issue was that there was a function returning linkedList output by value, in which case, the copy constructor would be called. the problem occurred when adding the value. the flag was false, which was supposed to be true. i also attached a snapshot below.

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H_
#define LINKEDLIST_H_


template<class T>
struct Node{
        T value;
        Node<T>* next;
    };


template<class T>
class linkedList
{

private:
    Node<T>* head;
public:

    bool isEmpty() const{ 
        if(!head)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    Node<T>* getHead() const{return head;}
    bool existVal(T value) const;
    void insertVal(T value);
    void deleteVal(T value){}

    linkedList(){ head = nullptr;}
    linkedList(const linkedList<T>& x);
    ~linkedList();




};


template<class T>
linkedList<T>::linkedList(const linkedList<T>& x){
    /*if(!x.isEmpty()){
    T val = x.getHead()->value;
    this->insertVal( val );
}

Node<T>* ptr1;
ptr1 = x.head;

while(ptr1){
    insertVal(ptr1->value);
    ptr1 = ptr1->next;

}*/
Node<T>* ptr = x.head;
while(ptr){
    T val = ptr->value;
    insertVal(val);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
}

template<class T>
void linkedList<T>::insertVal(T value){
    Node<T>* ptrNode = new Node<T>();


    Node<T>* ptr;
    ptr = head;
    bool flag = !head;
    if(flag){
        head = ptrNode;
        ptrNode->value = value;
    }
    else{
        while((ptr->next))
        {ptr = ptr->next;}
        ptr->next = ptrNode;
        ptrNode->value = value;
    }

    return;
}

template<class T>
linkedList<T>::~linkedList(){
    Node<T>* ptr;
    while(head){
        ptr = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete ptr;
    }
    ptr = nullptr;
}

template<class T>
bool linkedList<T>::existVal(T value) const{
    Node<T>* ptr;
    ptr = head;
    while(!ptr){
        if(ptr->value == value)
            return true;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return false;
}

#endif
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you expect `head` to obtain a value when a copy is made?

Comment: The copy constructor is too complicated.  All you need to do to make a copy is call `insertVal` with the data from the passed-in linked list in a simple loop.

Comment: In addition, what good is your linked list if you can't retrieve any data from it from the outside (i.e., from code that lies outside of your linked list class)?  You have a linked list, and it is useless as no data can be retrieved from it.  For example, where is the `getData` function?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie for the specific task im working right now, this doesnt matter. besides, i have simplified my copy constructor as u instructed.

Comment: @STNYU Then the problem is not the copy constructor if that is how it's written (more simplified).  The problem is with your `insertVal` function.  Also, the issue is that you need to make sure you start out with an empty list, which it seems you failed to do with your copy constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error right away is that you failed to initialize `head` to nullptr.

```
linkedList<T>::linkedList(const linkedList<T>& x) : head(nullptr) {
```

Once you do that, then the code should work.  If it doesn't work, then you should concentrate on the `insertVal` function, as all you're doing is calling `insertVal` in a loop (which is, give or take, the easiest and safest way to create a copy of your linked list).

Also, you should create an assignment operator along with the copy constructor, otherwise assigning a linked list to another will have memory leak/corruption issues.

Comment: problem solved! thx so much. ur other advice is also very helpful. the task im doing right now only requires a copy constructor. however, as my project keeps growing, an assignment operator is a must-have item.

Comment: Well, your current task may only require a copy constructor, but it is just wrong not to have a user defined assignment operator if a user defined copy constructor exists.  I'm saying this just in case you're taking a sub-par C++ course, where you may never be told about the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

In your copy constructor, head was never initialized to null. so head has a random address assigned to it and flag will be false (flag = !head);

In general, you should use initialization list over constructor for initializing member variables. Instead of creating a temporary variable and do an assignment, initialization list just assigns the value to the member variable.

```
linkedList()
    head(nullptr)
{
}

linkedList(const linkedList<T>& x)
    head(nullptr)
{
    // your code
}
```